# usb0 -> what exactly is it for?

Tags: linux, mount, usb, ethernet, media

So far, I found out that on GNU/Linux `/media/usb0` seems to be a mount point for [Ethernet over USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB). Nice.

**Question**: *Where is defined, what `usb0` is exactly for?*

I distilled the above mentioned suspicion from a lot of discussions where `usb0`is mentioned for Ethernet over USB. But I can't find any definition. Is there a history behind this?

---

**EDIT**: I found the following in [FHS 2.3 definitions](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html%2a%2a), section `/media`:

> On systems where more than one device exists for mounting a certain
>   type of media, mount directories can be created by appending a digit
>   to the name of those available above starting with '0', but the
>   unqualified name must also exist.

so the **[updated/additional] question**: *Is `usb0` meant for Ethernet over USB or is it just commonly used for this?*

Comment: are you aware of the UNIX philosophy that everything is a file?

Comment: oh actually, nevermind. misread your question. still, though, I've never seen `/mount/usb0` on my boxes. more than that, I've never seen `/mount`. that directory isn't in the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, either.

Comment: @strugee I am, yes. So what, beside the `0`, makes the difference between `file`and `file0`? Also: are you aware that one can delete comments if… for whatever reason ;)

Comment: Is it possible you mean `/mnt/usb0`? If that's the case, I don't think it's meant to represent Ethernet over USB specifically. It's a generic mountpoint that can be used to automount removable media over USB. At least that's how things are on my Debian box.

Comment: @JosephR. **MY BAD!**  Edited `/mount` to `media` Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @chirp No worries. I make that mistake a lot, too, because I'm used to sounding out the "mount" in my head whenever I think of `/mnt` (See also `/temp` mistaken for `/tmp` :D )

Answer (score 2):

The directory `/mnt` is a fairly old directory where resources, such as HDDs, are often mounted into the system. They're typically mounted from `/etc/fstab`, but do not have to be exclusively mounted from there.

If you're wondering where a resource such as `/mnt/usb0` is pointing to, or rather what device is "behind" it, you can use the `df` command to interrogate the situation a little further.

```
$ cd /mnt/usb0
$ df -h .
```

#### Example

Under several Linuxes the directory `/media` has become a pseudo standard location for mounting USB thumbdrives etc. On my laptop for example when I plug in a USB thumbdrive and `cd` to it's mounted directory it presents like so:

```
$ pwd
/media/KINGSTON

$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1             7.5G  6.4G  1.2G  86% /media/KINGSTON
```

You can use the above to try and get a better understanding of the device, if any, that may be behind the mount point `/mnt/usb0`.

Comment: **MY BAD! SORRY!!!**  Edited `/mount` to `mnt` Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @chirp - see updates.

Comment: `/media/usb` is a softlink to `/media/usb0` here (Debian based Crunchbang 10). Seriously, a softlink: Different inodes, differing in just one digit from `/media/usb` which has the lower inode and `/media/usb0` having the exactly next inode available (!).